# How do i solve this CSS object-fit issue?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, image

I'm trying to do an image uploader with an image preview in my React app.

I would like to display the `img` with the right proportions and cropped by its container.

This is the JSX:

```html
<div className="YourProfileImg">
  <img
  id="imagePreview"
  src={userData.image}
  />
</div>
```

The JSX seems to work fine, then I style my `#imagePreview` with `object-fit` in this way:

```css
#imagePreview {
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
}
```

this is the CSS applied to YourProfileImg:

```
.YourProfileImg {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 10px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

but seems to work only with some images.

For example here the image is stretched.

[image]

While here the image is not stretched.

[image]

Am I writing the code incorrectly or am I missing something?

Comment: can you share your working code snippet?

Comment: object-fit: cover should do the work. Are you sure that it is not overriden by any other css code?

Comment: Can you show the CSS applied to YourProfileImg?

Comment: @RicardoSanchez I've added it

Comment: Have you tried setting 100% the `width` and `height` on the `#imagePreview` selector?

Comment: @RicardoSanchez tried already, it doesn't work. It does the same type of error

Comment: @WilliamWang What do you mean, sorry? I'm kinda new to the dew world and I don't know what is a code snippet, sorry.